# How to switch between headphones and speakers manually

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones

I have an ASUS G60JX laptop with 12.04 installed. The laptop has the sound jack broken (the jack thinks that there are always headphones plugged in, even though there is nothing. So I can hear the laptop with headphones, but when I unplug them, the internal speakers are silent.)

Is there a way to switch between internal speakers and headphones manually?

Answer (score 2):

You can change using `System Settings->Sound->Output` - just pick the device you want the sound to output on.

Comment: I suppose this requires pulseaudio and using some specific desktop environment in ubuntu. But how to do it without pulseaudio using some specific tools?