# How to switch between headphones and speakers manually from command line

Tags: command-line, sound, alsa, headphones, speakers

What if I want to write a script that switches audio output? How can it be done under Ubuntu?

(There is a related question on Ask Ubuntu: [How to switch between headphones and speakers manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181186/how-to-switch-between-headphones-and-speakers-manuallye))

Here is the output of my `amixer -c 0` in case it is needed:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 52 [81%] [-12.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-64.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-64.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Bass Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 3 [100%] [30.00dB]
  Front Right: 3 [100%] [30.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958 Default PCM',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Beep',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch penum
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 31
  Front Left: Capture 22 [71%] [16.50dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 22 [71%] [16.50dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Enabled'
Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
```

Comment: Good question. I like to know too. I had already asked but no solution so far: http://askubuntu.com/questions/156895/how-to-switch-sound-output-with-key-shortcut

Comment: @rechengehirn I've updated my question to incorporate an advice you've got.

Comment: Something like this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/237835/script-to-switch-between-two-sound-devices

Comment: Ah this one is better: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1370383

Comment: No. AFAIK I have only one physical device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, use `alsamixer` to find out which mixer controls must be changed to get the desired effect.

Then write a script that runs [amixer](http://linux.die.net/man/1/amixer) to set those controls.
For example:

```
amixer set "Headphone" mute
amixer set "Speaker" unmute
```

In this case, it's likely that you also need to disable `Auto-Mute Mode`.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is what I am looking for. Unfortunately it seems, that the soundcard in my notebook is not capable of  simultaneous output to both speaker and headphones.

Comment: UPDATE! I was able to hear both streams simultaneously! I just needed to select the "Analog Output" as the sound device stream.